# Life of distributed cache in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

When files are transferred to nodes using the distributed cache mechanism in a Hadoop streaming job, does the system delete these files after a job is completed? If they are deleted, which i presume they are, is there a way to make the cache remain for multiple jobs? Does this work the same way on Amazon's Elastic Mapreduce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was digging around in the source code, and it looks like files are deleted by `TrackerDistributedCacheManager` about once a minute when their reference count drops to zero.  The `TaskRunner` explicitly releases all its files at the end of a task.  Maybe you should edit `TaskRunner` to not do this, and control the cache through more explicit means yourself?

Comment: That's a huge help. I think there might be other ways to get files loaded onto the nodes which I will explore. Distributed cache was just the method I was familiar with. Thanks for the code ref, that's amazingly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I [cross posted this question at the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56917) and got a good recommendation to use `hadoop fs -get` to transfer files in a way that persists across jobs.